# What is the PowerShell "Search" verb for?

Tags: powershell

The MSDN page "[Approved Verbs for Windows PowerShell Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx)" says:

> The **Find** verb is used to look for an object. The **Search** verb is used to create a reference to a resource in a container.

What does "create a reference to a resource in a container" mean? Does it mean defining a new name for an existing resource? Does it mean taking some information about a resource and converting that information into a reference? Or does it mean something else?

What's an example of how the "Search" verb is intended to be used? And what does this action have to do with searching?

Comment: For that matter, what's the difference between `Get`, `Find`, `Search` and `Select`?  Why `Get-Content` and not `Read-Content`?  Why `Get-ChildItem` and not `Find-ChildItem` or `Search-ChildItem`?  This is why I don't like the approved verb list.  Well, that and the fact that it makes tab completion significantly less powerful when you have to type 5-8 characters to get to the unique bits.

Comment: `$(Locate-HumanReadableVerbExplanationFile).FullName | Find-MeaningOf -Verb Search`

Comment: Locate-HumanReadableVerbExplanationFile : The term 'Locate-HumanReadableVerbExplanationFile' is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: I think I can answer why it's `Get-Content` instead of `Read-Content`. This is just speculation, but my understanding is that "Get" is for getting a collection of objects, an *entire* object, or the *entire* contents of an object, while "Read" is for getting a *piece* of information from an object. A command called `Read-Content` would presumably give you only *part* of the contents of an item.

Comment: @TannerSwett: @TannerSwett: I think the distinction between `Get` and `Read` is not so much much about _partial_ information, but about retrieving the _object itself_ vs. _its contents_.
Thus, `Get-Content`, as an _usual_ example of a `Get` cmdlet, should arguably just be called  `Read`, but `Read` by itself obviously violates the verb-noun convention.
(`Get-Content` is unusual in that the noun part doesn't refer to the target entity type; it basically says "get me what's inside of it", without naming that _it_; the latter is what cmdlets usually do, such as in `Get-ADUser`.)

Comment: @mklement0 That's what I thought originally, but the `Get-Clipboard` cmdlet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt736727.aspx) gets the contents of the clipboard, rather than an object representing the clipboard.

Comment: @TannerSwett: `Get-Clipboard` should probably be `Get-ClipboardItem` (the help page talks about "entries"), so I'd say that it's just another example of ill-applied conventions.
I guess `Read` carries a connotation of retrieving something unstructured that can be partitioned arbitrarily (such as reading bytes from a file), which is perhaps why there
are few cmdlets named `Read-*`, given that PowerShell is all about _structured_ information (objects and their properties); afterthought re `Get-Content`: arguably, it should be `Read-Item`, to parallel `Get-Item`.

Answer (score 11):

**tl;dr**

- The **distinction between `Search` and `Find` is *ill-defined*** in the realm of PowerShell.
- **Existing, Microsoft-originated modules reflect this confusion**, arbitrarily coming with *either* `Find-*` *or* `Search-*` cmdlets, but not *both*.
- **To resolve this, ask Microsoft for clarification**, which can result in either :

  - a useful distinction between `Search` and `Find` that needs to be *explained* and can then guide future implementations.
  - *or* declaring one verb a (legacy) *synonym* of the other, and making a recommendation to only use *one* going forward.

---

Human language is ambiguous, which is invariably at odds with PowerShell's commendable quest for consistency, as documented in [Approved Verbs for Windows PowerShell Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands).

Regrettably, that document itself contains many ill-defined terms (as of this writing), used vaguely interchangeably, such as *resource*, *object*, *item*, *target*, and *reference*.

Somewhat ironically, the document admonishes:

> To enforce consistency across cmdlets, do not use a synonym of an approved verb.

**Arguably, in English *find* and *search* ARE synonyms**, with only the degree of certainty about the *outcome* distinguishing them: ***search* is more open-ended than *find***: you may search without result, but to find implies a successful outcome.

**Is this distinction worth making when it comes to naming cmdlets?**

**Arguably *not***, which is reflected in real-world Microsoft implementations - such as the Active Directory, Exchange, and PowerShellGet modules - *choosing one term to the exclusion of the other*.

Again, somewhat ironically, said document seems to *reverse* the human-language relationship between *find* and *search*:

- `Find`

> Looks for an object in a container that is unknown, implied, optional, or specified.

- `Search`

> Creates a reference to a resource in a container.

Leaving aside the ambiguity around *object* vs. *container* (and what a *reference* is in this context), it is the `Find` definition here that sounds more open-ended than `Search` - in opposition to human language (English).

---

[felixfbecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4208018/felixfbecker) observes the following with respect to the *noun* part of `Search-*` and `Find-*` cmdlets:

> I think another difference is that the noun in **`Search-Noun`** **describes *what is searched* [the search *space*]** while the noun in **`Find-Noun`** describes ***what is being searched for* [the *kind of item*]**. Therefore, e.g., a cmdlet `Search-Wikipedia` makes sense, whereas `Find-Wikipedia` does not. `Find-WikipediaArticle` and `Search-Wikipedia-Article`, on the other hand, both make sense, but mean different things.

This is a useful distinction, but it hasn't been observed in practice, as the example of `Search-ADAccount` shows. [Vinny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7687952/vinny) notes that, by this logic, the name should be `Find-ADAccount`, given that it looks *for* accounts; or, with `Search`, it should be `Search-AD`.

Comment: The last note regarding felixfbecker's observation makes most sense to me, especially when comparing the out-of-the-box `Find-*` cmdlets vs the one `Search-*` cmdlet.  `Search-ADAccount` searches for an AD Account that could belong to a User, Computer, or Service Account.  It really doesn't know what specific type of object it's looking for, but it is searching an entire bucket of AD accounts based on a criteria.

Comment: Good point, @Vinny - I've added your observation to the answer: please see my update at the bottom.

Comment: @mklement0 here the updated link for approved verbs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.3

Also, any thoughts on adding select to your explanation? It seems to overlap with find as well. Example: Linguistically, I would expect Select-String to be Find-String, as you are searching for the string that may or may not exist, as opposed to, e.g., select-object, where you are intentionally targeting an existing object. MSFT has named it select, though. Or should I ask about this in a new question?

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Blaisem - answer updated. Good point about `Select-String`. Certainly, given the existence of `findstr.exe`, `Find-String` is probably easier to discover, and, yes, to _select_ has connotations of selecting a subset from a _known_ set. Given that this question post is about `Search`, I suggest you ask a new question if you want to explore this further.

Answer (score 1):

The only example of `Search-` that I know of is `Search-ADAccount` and it really doesn't do us any favors in terms of making this less ambiguous. It returns the same kind of object as `Get-ADUser`/`Get-ADComputer`/`Get-ADObject`, and it has search criteria that aren't available in the `Get-` cmdlets, even though those support filtering and "searching" as well.

Answer (score 1):

**What would make sense**
`Find-` cmdlets look **for** the noun of the cmdlet:

`Find-Command` looks **for** *command*(s)

`Search-` cmdlets look **inside** the noun of the cmdlet:

`Search-Repository` might look **inside** a repository for various items.

`Search-ADForest` might look **inside** an Active Directory Forest for various AD objects.

**What actually is the case**
In reality, **search** seems to be used as a synonym for the verb **find**. There could be slight distinctions between the two, but the nuances are ill defined. This is not in accordance with Microsoft's own guidance on verb usage for cmdlet names, and as such **search** should become deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking `Get` commands are used to retrieve information for further processing, wheras the `Search` commands are used to make it easier to sort out unknowns.

If  I was writing a script I'd likely want to use `Get-AdUser` command to get information, however if I wasn't au fait with the specific parameters or the ability to pipe and sort by property, I may find it easier to have another commandlet with common tab-completed variables.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties LastLogonDate | ? {$_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-3)}
```

is quite a long command to get people who haven't logged in for 3 months, however..

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive
```

does a similar job with much less input, and if i'm just piping names to Csv, they're functionally identical.

obviously the designers of powershell expected `Search` commands to be used as shorthand versions of common `Get` commands, however it didn't really catch on, probably because normal people like you and me actually have these questions regarding why someone would ever use one over the other.

Comment: Why is "Search" a more appropriate verb than "Find" for the `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question.

Find is used to look for objects. However, when it comes to things like - Groups, computers, account. These are termed as "resources". And we know that resources are always contained inside a container. As they do not exist as objects in an Active Directory.

Since we already have defined "Find" to look for object, we need another verb, so we can "Search" for "resources" inside a "container".

Below is the description of search-adaccount:

Search-ADAccount
Gets Active Directory user, computer, or service accounts.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that Find looks for "objects"  while Search looks for "resources". Is that correct? What's the difference between an "object" and a "resource", then? Does "object" mean a .NET object?

Comment: yes, Find looks for "Objects" and Search looks for "Resources".

Powershell is built on .NET framework. Behind the scenes all the objects are built on the .NET, however the "type" of an object can be different in different situations.

Example:
Processes in powershell are .NET objects of type - "System.Diagnostics.Process" 

If you want to know the "type" of an object at any time, just do a "Get-Member" on that. OR call the "getType()" method.

Comment: But doesn't the `Search-ADAccount` cmdlet return objects of the class Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount, in exactly the same way that the `Get-Process` cmdlet returns objects of the class System.Diagnostics.Process? Are you saying that an Active Directory account is a "resource" but a process is not? If so, what's the difference?

Comment: Resources and objects are in many ways similar, but in other ways completely opposite. An object has behavior but no visible state. It responds to messages, passing more objects along. Resources themselves have no behavior. They are just bare state. Also, the o/p of a cmdlet is always an object so you can pipe it to another cmdlets for further processing.

Comment: You're going to need to be way more precise about the difference between an object and a resource. I'm going to ask again: does "object" in this context mean a .NET object? And are you saying that an Active Directory account is a resource but a process is not?

Comment: yes, "object" in this context refers to .NET object. As per what I researched, Active Directory user, computer, and service accounts seems to be treated as resources.